# Spring security, allow only https connection and send error otherwise

Tags: rest, redirect, spring-security, https

i have some REST services and, as requirement, the caller is allowed to invoke them only by https: on every attempt of using http, the request must be rejected by sending back a customized json error response.
In spring security, i don't know how to implement this behaviour...the only thing i was able to do is to include this configuration:

.and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()

but the result was a trasparent redirect that, despite acceptable and maybe "right", does not fulfill the requirement.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `ChannelProcessor` that processes your request is `SecureChannelProcessor`, and it uses a `RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint`, which performs the redirect. Instead, provide your own entry point to the default processor:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //...
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
                            .channelProcessors(
                                Arrays.asList(mySecureChannelProcessor())
                            );
    }
}

    @Bean
    public ChannelProcessor mySecureChannelProcessor() {
        SecureChannelProcessor defaultProcessor = new SecureChannelProcessor();
        defaultProcessor.setEntryPoint(new SendHttpsError());
        return defaultProcessor;
    }

}


public class SendHttpsError implements ChannelEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // send error
    }
}
```

If you’re using Spring Boot, you can `@Autowire` the `ObjectMapper` instance that is created by default (if Jackson is on the class path) and provide it to your entry point.